# How to process files in separate threads?

Tags: multithreading, spring-integration

How to process files in separate threads?

There is a /local dir where files are being put by other means and new files with same name replace old ones.
I want move files from /local to /processing dir and activate some service. Further in the end of filter chain a cleanup task will remove files from /processing.
I made it working 1 by 1, but processing takes minutes so I'd like to

1. Add multithreading: i.e. Several files are moved and processed simultaneously.
2. If there is a file that was not yet processed say "File1.abc" and a new version of this file has been put to /local then no need to process old message with old version of file. I.e. messages should be sent only for version of files in the moment they are moved from /local to /processing

I am trying something like this:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="processingChannel"
                               directory="#{localDir}"
                               prevent-duplicates="false" filter="acceptAllFileListFilter">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="20" max-messages-per-poll="3" task-executor="executor"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="3" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="ABORT"/>

<file:outbound-gateway      request-channel="processingChannel"   reply-channel="serviceChannel"
                               directory="#{processing}"
                               auto-create-directory="true"
                               filename-generator-expression="payload.name + '_' + { T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()}"
                               delete-source-files="true"
                               mode="FAIL" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel" output-channel="furtherChannels"
                       ref="someService" method="process">
</int:service-activator>

<bean id="someService" class="com.dot.SomeService"/>
```

But it does not work and I cannot figure out how to fix it. I tried different ways but there are always errors like messages are generated for already deleted files or some other problems. The task itself seems simple. How to make files process in say 3 threads and send messages only for actual versions of files? Maybe problem here with polling consumer but inbound adapter is used only with this consumer, right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see solution for you yet, but maybe you just don't explain the challenge properly... Try just share the business requirements.

Plus I don't see reason for the `<file:outbound-gateway>`. You can just read files from the `/local` dir and process them. For the concurrency and some discard in-flight processes logic you could use some custom `FileListFilter`, from where you should determine the new file version and by its key `cancel()` the ran process to start a new one in the end of current `poll()`.

There might be some other solution, but let's start just from the business requirements!

Comment: I moved files with  `<file:outbound-gateway>` because from on side messages should be sent always since new version of files may arrive and from the other side messages should not be processed (or even sent) more than once. I thought moving files helps to solve this issue. But if use custom `FileListFilter` then i suppose it's not necessary.

Business requirements are simple:

1. Process files simultaniously in separate threads.

2. Do not process old version of file if there is a new one exists.

All other things like moving from one dir to another are optional.

Thank you.